# Multivariate Markov Regime switching GARCH in R

Tags: volatility

I am looking for R package handling Multivariate Markov Regime switching GARCH models, but MSGARCH package only work for univariate time series.

Any suggestion would be welcomed, thanks!

Comment: If you do not find any multivariate MSGARCH packages you can always model the interdependence using the Dynamic Conditional Correlation (DCC) structure of Engle. The decomposition allows for a separate modeling of the correlation- and volatility-dynamics, hence implying that you can use the MSGARCH model to univariately fit on each asset. That could be one method to get what you want.

Comment: Copula-GARCH models are another alternative based on a similar logic to what Pleb has suggested. Model each series with MSGARCH and then model the joint distribution of standardized residuals using a copula.